Writing the regular FG-module as the direct sum of irreducible FG-modules
Let $G=<g>$ be the cyclic group of order $5$ and $F$ be the field with $2$ elements. Prove that the regular $FG$-module is the direct sum of two irreducibles $FG$-modules.
My first thought was to find an $FG$-endomorphism $\theta: FG \rightarrow FG$ such that $\theta^2=\theta$ (for example $\sum_{i=0}^4 \lambda_ig^i \rightarrow (\sum_{i=0}^4 \lambda_ i)g $).
Then, I would have that $FG$ is the direct sum of $ker\theta$ and $im\theta$ where $im\theta$ is irreducible as it has dimension 1. I have trouble showing that $ker\theta$ is irreducible.
Any ideas?

Try looking at elements where the sum of coefficients is zero.

@SteveD I know that the kernel is consisted exactly from these elements. But I cannot conclude that the kernel is irreducible. Also, if I'm correct, we have that $ker\theta=span(1+a, 1+a^2, 1+a^3, 1+a^4)$

Your map is not a good idea IMO, because the image is a $F$ subspace, but not an $FG$ one. Instead, work directly with the subspace I mentioned. Show it has a complement and that both are $FG$ modules. To show irreducibility, use the basis you wrote and consider what $a$ does. How you conclude depends on your preference: you can use linear algebra (you have a linear operator on a vector space), or group theory (you have a group acting on a finite set).

Let $V$ be the regular $FG$ module. Then $V^G=\{v\in V\mid gv=v\ \forall g\in G\}$ is an $FG$ submodule, and $W=\{\sum\lambda_ig^i\mid\sum\lambda_i=0\}$ is as well. I leave it to you to show $V^G\cap W=\{0\}$ (hint: $5$ doesn't divide $2$) and $V=V^G+W$ (hint: count dimensions).
It's clear $V^G$ is simple, hence irreducible. Let's show $W$ is simple as well (side note: by Maschke's theorem, simple and irreducible are two sides of the same coin). Now $W$ is a $4$-dimensional vector space over $F$, so $|W|=16$. $G$ acts on this subspace, with fixed points given by $W\cap V^G=\{0\}$. Since $|G|=5$ is prime, all other $G$-orbits have size $5$. If $W$ had an $FG$ submodule $M$, it would be an $F$-vector subspace, so $|M|=2^m$ for $0\le m\le 4$. It would also be a union of $G$-orbits, so $|M|=1+5k$ for some $k\ge 0$. Equating the two expressions we have
\begin{equation*}
2^m = 1+5k \qquad(0\le m\le4)
\end{equation*}
And the only solutions to that are $(m=0,k=0)$ and $(m=4,k=3)$, corresponding to $M=\{0\}$ and $M=W$. Thus $W$ is simple, hence irreducible.
